# Return exit status code from inline Expect command

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

How do you make Expect to return the exit status codes rather than a 0 or 1 when executing expect -c.

For example, after executing the following line I expect to have "17" returned, but instead I get "0" signalling that the command successfully ran.

```
expect -c "spawn echo \"foo\"; expect { -re \"foo\" { exit 17 } }"; echo $?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little testing I found that this:

```
expect -c "spawn echo foo; expect \"\n-re . {puts OK}\""
```

which is equivalent to the following Expect script:

```
spawn echo foo; expect {
-re . {puts OK}}
```

works as expected. But if you remove the `\n` it will fail. So Expect uses only the multiline syntax when the first character of the argument is a new line. Otherwise it tries to use that for matching, in your case it tries to match `-re "foo" { exit 17 }`. If you add a `exp_internal 1` at the beginning, expect will output this line:

```
expect: does "foo\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern " -re "foo" { exit 17 } "? no
```

So simply omit the `{}` for the expect group.
The correct statement should be:

```
expect -c "spawn echo \"foo\"; expect -re \"foo\" { exit 17 }"; echo $?
```